# How to obtain individual strings returned from GetPrivateProfileSection()

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I normally use Java for programming. I have only basic knowledge of C++. I am currently using JNI to call the Windows API GetPrivateProfileSection().

I understand that I have to write a C++ function to do this. I am vaguely familiar with how to do this. The problem I face is the returned C++ string from GetPrivateProfileSection().

From the Microsoft documentation, I understand that the returned string contains name=value pairs each separated by a NULL character. The last name=value pair ends with 2 NULL characters.

What I want to do is to collect all the individual name=value strings and put them in an array. I have absolutely no clue as to how to do this with the returned string from GetPrivateProfileSection(). I have heard that I need to do something known as pointer arithmetics but I have no knowledge how to do this.

Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that reads INI file to std::map looks like this:

```
LPTSTR str_settings = new TCHAR[bufferSize];

::GetPrivateProfileSection(_T("MySection"), str_settings , bufferSize, _T("MyIni.ini"));

std::map<std::string, std::string> settings; // map key -> value from ini file
std::string sett_string;

for (;*str_settings; str_settings += sett_string.length() + 1)
{
   sett_string = str_settings;

   size_t pos = sett_string.find('=');
   std::string key;
   std::string value;

   if (pos == std::string::npos)
   {
      key = sett_string;
   }
   else
   {
      key.assign(sett_string.begin(), sett_string.begin() + pos);
      value.assign(sett_string.begin() + pos + 1, sett_string.end());
   }

   settings[key] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I experimented with your source codes in a test C++ program and it worked well. One thing I noticed is that the std::map class is very similar to the Java Properties class.

My goal now is to get each name=value pair and concat them back-to-back in a C++ string with each name=value pair separated by a \r\n.

After experimenting for some time, I finally came up with the following code which seem to work:

```
void DoTest()
{
const int bufferSize = 1024;
LPTSTR str_settings = new TCHAR[bufferSize];
// Keep the original pointer. Need to delete later.
LPTSTR str_settings_original = str_settings;
// Another string to keep all name=value pairs back to back separated by \r\n.
LPTSTR str_settings_concatenated = new TCHAR[bufferSize];

// I keep getting crash until I tried the following :
// put a NULL character at the beginning of str_settings_concatenated.
str_settings_concatenated[0] = NULL;

::GetPrivateProfileSection(_T("MySection"), str_settings , bufferSize, _T("MyIni.ini"));

std::string sett_string;

for (;*str_settings; str_settings += sett_string.length() + 1)
{
sett_string = str_settings;
// str_settings effectively points to the next name=value pair
// and this is what I really want. I take advantage of this
// and pack them back-to-back into str_settings_concatenated
// separated by \r\n.
strcat(str_settings_concatenated, str_settings);
strcat(str_settings_concatenated, "\r\n");
}

delete str_settings_original;
str_settings_original = NULL;

delete str_settings_concatenated;
str_settings_concatenated = NULL;
}
```

Important points:

- I used your for loop construct to obtain each name=value pair in str_settings.
- In every iteration of the for loop, str_settings seemed to always get the next name=value pair which works well for me even though I have honestly no clue how the code works (but many thanks to you).
- I created another C++ string to store each name=value pair each separated by a \r\n. I used strcat() to do this.
- I initially got many crashes and str_settings_concatenated did not appear to get any of the strings.
- I also recall that in C++ we must call a delete to every memory allocation using new. I tried this and it did not help. However, I got some advice from a friend that told me I should put a NULL character at the beginning of str_settings_concatenated.

The code now works well. If you don't mind, could you also point out any other errors present in the code?

Once again, thanks very much for the help.

David.

P.S.: sorry for using the Answer option to post this. Was unable to post this as a comment due to character limitations.